# GNUPlot matrix plot with changing distance between lines

Tags: gnuplot

In GNUPlot you can make 3d plots based on a .dat file with a matrix notation:

```
#Y 0.1  0.2  0.3  0.4
    0    1    4    9   #X =  1
    1    2    5   10   #X =  2
    4    5    8   13   #X =  3
    9   10   13   18   #X =  5
   16   17   20   25   #X =  7
   25   26   29   34   #X = 10
```

However the file I want to plot has some changes in X-distance between the lines. As shown in comment. One can use `set xtics` but that only changes the numbers on the plot, while the points should be plotted on a linear axis.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, not with this type of matrix notation.  You would have to use a format as described here: [http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/datafile-e.html#3dim](http://web.archive.org/web/20110721044143/http://t16web.lanl.gov/Kawano/gnuplot/datafile-e.html)

The matrix format assumes an even spacing between x and y points, but the 3D data format allows arbitrary positioning of all the points.